# Copy XML element to String

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML file copy to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533507/xml-file-copy-to-a-string)

```
 <DETAIL Description='>> Problem:<br><br>CRS750 dumps when panel F is opened<br><br><br>  <br>>> Functional Solution:<br><br>Check cause of the dump and fix it<br><br><br><br>>> Technical Solution:<br><br>Modified CRS750 and added fields WWVTRM and WWCRTP in CRA750F0 record format.<br><br><br><br>>> Related corrections<br><br>None <br><br><br><br>>> Affected Objects<br><br>CRS750 VIEWDEF MAT only' />
```

I would like to copy  the above string and update the table in database with the value in the string .

However , since it contains `<br>` and `<<`  its throwing the below exception;

```
'<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 1, position 902.
```

tag like this works good `<DETAIL Objects='MAT: Viewdefinition:CRS750' />` Please suggest

Comment: Research [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

Comment: The problem are the '>' and '<' characters - replace with &lt; and &gt; accordingly

Comment: @Pawel, while it somewhat correct I doubt it is good recommendation - next question would be "how to use RegEx to select wrong `<` in XML-like string"...

Comment: @Alexei: The content is not an Xml document/fragment (not well-formed), so I don't really see a problem with using regex here. The problem here is the source that generates the above Xml document. I could also believe that originally the content of the attribute was actually encoded but was pretty-printed (e.g. by Internet Explorer which displays &lt; as black '<' etc.) and the result here is the result of copying user-friendly rendered document and not the actual Xml document itself. Possibly you could try using an SGML parser here...

Comment: @Pawel, I strongly doubt that such string was intentionally typed in by user (in which case fixing it up is somewhat ok, also asking to retype would be my choice :) )... Much more likely it is generated by some code - fixing the code that produces "XML" is much more efficient solution (granted that such approach is significantly less fun - creating XLMAgilityPack as pair to HTMLAgilityPack is interesting but I think counterproductive).

Answer (score 1):

Your string is not valid XML, there is no way to put it in place that requires XML.

String.Concat is not a way to construct XML. Please use XML API (XmlDocument, XDocument or XmlWriter) to create XML.

If you still want to construct XML by hand with string.Concat please prove that you've read [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) before asking questions.